# local storage security

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use phone gap and create a new db via following command.

```
var dbShell = window.openDatabase(name, version, display_name, size);
```

I just want to save a username or emailadress with a timestamp in it. Nothing special. Who has access to this data on SQL-Lite db on iOS 5/6? Or can see it?